# Passing HTML variable to use in python function

Tags: python, html

I am trying to pass an input variable in a form tag to use in a python function. However, I keep getting different HTTP errors. I have changed the code numerous times drawing reference from other questions on the stack, none of them have worked.

The problem seems to be with the URL, the input variable appears in the URL but I may not be handling it correctly. I'm also getting an error sometimes with the 'attempted_question' not being recognized.

Any help appreciated

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body class = "body">
    <body>
      <form  action="{{ url_for('about') }}" method=”PUT”>
        <label> Enter population based question:  </label>
        <input name = "pop_question" >
        <button type=”submit”> Submit </button>
      </form>
      <p> </p>
  </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**pass.html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body class = "body">
    <body>
      <p> i am here {{ attempted_question }}</p>
  </body>
  </body>
</html>
</html>
```

run.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about", methods=['GET'])
def about():

    living = request.form['pop_question']
    return render_template('pass.html', attempted_question=living )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: did you try to add `POST` in your allowed methods. ( replace `methods=['GET']` by `methods=['GET', 'POST']`)

Comment: I have tried this, and still didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: when adding both POST and GET, i get a werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError saying the pop_question is a KeyError, although it follows the format from other answers that worked

Answer (score 0):

You use different http methods when sending and receiving data.
Try to use same method. 'POST' for example.

index.html

```
...
<form  action="{{ url_for('about') }}" method=”POST”>
...
```

run.py

```
...
@app.route("/about", methods=['POST'])
...
```

Comment: This still didnt work, there a method not allowed 405 error now